# C# Difference between First() and Find()

Tags: c#, linq, list, c#-4.0

So I know that `Find()` is only a `List<T>` method, whereas `First()` is an extension for any `IEnumerable<T>`. I also know that `First()` will return the first element if no parameter is passed, whereas `Find()` will throw an exception. Lastly, I know that `First()` will throw an exception if the element is not found, whereas `Find()` will return the type's default value.

I hope that clears up confusion about what I'm actually asking. This is a computer science question and deals with these methods at the computational level. I've come to understand that `IEnumerable<T>` extensions do not always operate as one would expect under the hood. So here's the Q, and I mean from a "close to the metal" standpoint: What is the difference between `Find()` and `First()`?

Here's some code to provide basic assumptions to operate under for this question.

```
var l = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var x = l.First(i => i == 3);
var y = l.Find(i => i == 3);
```

Is there any actual computational difference between how `First()` and `Find()` discover their values in the code above?

Note: Let us ignore things like `AsParallel()` and `AsQueryable()` for now.

Comment: First() will create an enumerator, Find() won't.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here's the code for `List<T>.Find` (from Reflector):

```
public T Find(Predicate<T> match)
{
    if (match == null)
    {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < this._size; i++)
    {
        if (match(this._items[i]))
        {
            return this._items[i];
        }
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

And here's `Enumerable.First`:

```
public static TSource First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    if (predicate == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    }
    foreach (TSource local in source)
    {
        if (predicate(local))
        {
            return local;
        }
    }
    throw Error.NoMatch();
}
```

So both methods work roughly the same way: they iterate all items until they find one that matches the predicate. The only noticeable difference is that `Find` uses a `for` loop because it already knows the number of elements, and `First` uses a foreach loop because it doesn't know it.

Comment: What is this Reflector and how do I get it?

Comment: It's a .NET disassembler, you can get it for free from Redgate: http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/. The Pro version isn't free, but it allows you to step through the code of framework or third-party assemblies.

Comment: Thanks. So the foreach creates an enumerator then, right? Do we have code for that from yon Reflector?

Comment: foreach doesn't create an enumerator, it consumes it. The enumerator is created by the list. You can look at the definition of List<T>.GetEnumerator if you want to see the code.

Comment: Why does the `Find` know the number of elements and `First` does not?

Comment: @gdoron, because `Find` is a method of the `List<T>` class, so it can just access the `Count` property. `First`, on the other hand, is an extension method that works on `IEnumerable<T>`, which doesn't have a `Count` property.

Comment: Dang it, the free version of Reflector now only comes with a 14-day trial :(

Comment: @pcnThird, Reflector stopped being free a long time ago, but there are several free alternatives. Check out JustDecompile (Telerik), dotPeek (Jetbrains) or ILSpy (open-source)

Comment: Accepted answer is wrong. 'The only noticeable difference' is that First() throws exception if no match is found while Find() returns default value (in most cases null). This means that if you use Find and get null, you do not know whether it means 'no match found' or 'found null element in sequence'.

Comment: @synek317 The original poster mentioned that they already knew about the differences in exception raising and were more worried about how the actual finding code itself worked. In that context, I think this answer is correct.

Comment: I definitely recommend DnSpy as decompiler. It allows you to even debug in the code.

Answer (score 32):

`First` will throw an exception when it finds nothing, `FirstOrDefault` however does exactly the same as `Find` (apart from how it iterates through the elements).

Answer (score 6):

BTW Find is rather equal to `FirstOrDefault()` than to `First()`. Because if predicate of `First()` is not satisfied with any list elements you will get an exception.
Here what returns a [dotpeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), another great free reflector replacement with some of ReSharper features

Here for `Enumerable.First(...)` and `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(...)` extension methods:

```
    public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
        foreach (TSource element in source) { 
            if (predicate(element)) return element;
        } 
        return default(TSource); 
    }


    public static TSource First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source"); 
        if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate"); 
        foreach (TSource element in source) {
            if (predicate(element)) return element; 
        }
        throw Error.NoMatch();
    }
```

and here is for List<>.Find:

```
/// <summary>
/// Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, and returns the first occurrence within the entire <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.List`1"/>.
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <returns>
/// The first element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, if found; otherwise, the default value for type <paramref name="T"/>.
/// </returns>
/// <param name="match">The <see cref="T:System.Predicate`1"/> delegate that defines the conditions of the element to search for.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="match"/> is null.</exception>
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public T Find(Predicate<T> match)
{
  if (match == null)
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
  for (int index = 0; index < this._size; ++index)
  {
    if (match(this._items[index]))
      return this._items[index];
  }
  return default (T);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to get the code for `FirstOrDefault` or `First`? Your current method is named `First<T>`..

Comment: have corrected my post. `Find()` and `FirstOrDefault()` are returning `default(T)` if nothing found. `First()` however throws an `InvalidOperationException`

Comment: According to the info from intellisense, *Find()* will throw an exception if there's no matching elements. That makes it work much more similarly to *First()* than *FirstOrDefault()*, contrary to your statement in the reply. Have I misunderstood the point?

Comment: Find() throws an ArgumentNullException if "match" argument is null, not if there are no matching elements

Answer (score 6):

1-  `Find()` returns `Null` if the entity is not in the context but `First()` will throw an exception
2-  `Find()` returns entities that have been added to the context but have not yet been saved to the database

Answer (score 2):

Since `List<>` is not indexed in any way, it has to go through all values to find a specific value. Therefore it doesn't make much of a difference compared to traversing the list via an enumerable (apart from the creation of a enumerable helper object instance).

That said, keep in mind that the `Find` function was created way earlier than the `First` extension method (Framework V2.0 vs. V3.5), and I doubt that they would have implemented `Find` if the `List<>` class had been implemented at the same time as the extension methods.