# Is Find preferred over First, or vice versa, in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

This code works:

```
public SiteMapping GetById(int ID)
{
    var entity = siteMappings.First(p => p.Id == ID);
    return entity == null ? null : entity;
}
```

...and so does this (with the same result):

```
public SiteMapping GetById(int ID)
{
    var entity = siteMappings.Find(p => p.Id == ID);
    return entity == null ? null : entity;
}
```

Is there a reason to prefer one (First, or Find) over the other?

### UPDATE

So, using Reed's suggestion, all I need is this:

```
public SiteMapping GetById(int ID)
{
    return = siteMappings.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == ID);
}
```

...and it's safe / it fails gracefully (or not at all, of course, when provided a proper ID val).

Comment: `entity == null ? null : entity` is the same as `entity`

Comment: is this LINQ to Sql or just Linq to objects

Comment: See this thread for more information on `Find()` and `First()`.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369040/c-sharp-difference-between-first-and-find although this smells of an opinion based question..

Comment: @elgonzo your result will always be null if entity is null.. Thats the point @SLaks was making. Therefore that call is redundant. 'object ?? null' will only execute the code after the '??' if the object is null. Therefore if the `object` is `null` then return `null`?

Comment: @Nico Id say this is a dup of that question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`First` will raise an exception if the object is not found.  `FirstOrDefault` would be more similar to `Find`.  Note that, in your first example, the null check (which should be eliminated, and just written as `return entity;`, as the ternary is not useful) will never happen if the `Id` is not found, as the method will raise an exception.

`FirstOrDefault` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`, which means that it will work in more scenarios than a `Find` method, which is a method defined on a specific class.

If this is `List<T>.Find`, both `FirstOrDefault` and `Find` will be O(n) and have basically the same performance, so there is no definitive advantage to either.  I'd generally prefer `FirstOrDefault` just for the fact that it's a bit more flexible, and would allow you to change the collection type without having to change your method.

Comment: Cool - using FirstOrDefault(), I no longer have to czech for null - it fails gracefully if I pass a nonexistent ID.