# Is the Find() method useless?

Tags: c#, list, linq, optimization, iteration

I've been doing some research into the differences between the two linq methods `Find()` and `First()`. The only differences I could find (pun intended) was that `Find()` uses a `foreach` loop instead of a `for` loop, and `First()` does not require a parameter to be called.

So is there any reason that I should use `Find()` instead of `First()`?

**EDIT:** I have already read [C# Difference between First() and Find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369040/c-sharp-difference-between-first-and-find)
, but it does not give any reason to use one over the other. It merely discusses how the two iterate over the list differently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Difference between First() and Find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369040/c-sharp-difference-between-first-and-find)

Comment: Find() does not require a parameter to be called. I believe this statement is wrong as Find require "predicate" as a parameter.

Comment: Find() is not LINQ extension and is collection specific (List.Find, Array.Find, etc..), and therefore is generally faster than LINQ extensions

Comment: @Rawitas Krungkaew That was an error on my part. I meant to say First() does not require a parameter. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly style preference, but for some cases there is difference.

`Find` is defined on limited set of types (`List<T>`, array) while `First` is defined as extension for all `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable` types. Using `First` allows you to change underlying collection type easily including using results of `.Where` and `.Select` methods. Converting enumerable to one that supports `.Find` is always slower option than just calling `.First`.

Performance of both methods is roughly the same on types they both defined as both simply do linear search through elements. More info in question you've linked - [C# Difference between First() and Find()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369040/c-sharp-difference-between-first-and-find)

If you have "queryable" enumeration (when using LINQ-to-SQL for example) using `.First` could be significantly faster than converting result to collection that support `.Find` (i.e. using `.ToList`) and than calling `.Find`. Such queryable enumeration likely convert `.First` into database specific query that will return one result while `.ToList` will likely have to pull in much more results for client side filtering.